# Restricting access to documents to facebook friends in mongodb

Tags: node.js, facebook, mongodb, facebook-graph-api, mongoose

I'm building a simple photo storage app that has three resources using mongodb mongoose:

- Users
- Albums
- Photos

All authentication is handled by passportjs.

A user can have many albums and an album can have many photos by using [parent references](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/).

The albums each have a different privacy setting:

- Private - Only the create can see it
- Public - Anyone can see it
- Friends - Only people who are (facebook) friends can see it

When I make a query for many albums I want to see a mixture of the 3 based on the user logged in but my question how should I check if the user logged in is a facebook friend with the creator?

Facebook provides an [endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends) to check if 2 users are friends but this would mean iterating through a collection and making a request on each and filtering the results and then finally returning them, which to me, seems like a lot of leg work.

Another approach (still without flaws):

1. User signs up and allows the app to get the friends already using the app
2. Store these friends _id in an array on the user
3. When a user creates an album, save a copy of this array onto a field on the album
4. Query using the $in operator using the logged in users ID

Pros:

- List item
- Quickly check if the user is a friend of the user who created the album
- No additional requests needed to facebook

Cons:

- Friend list is set once, so if friend list changes it needs to be updated somehow
- Friend list is in multiple locations (on user and on x number of albums) so needs to be updated across all these somehow
- When a new friend signs up, that may already have friends on the app, we would need to find each of those friends and add the new friend to their friends list and also remove if need be.

These are the only ways I can think of, can anyone offer new methods or perhaps improvements to the ones above? Maybe I'm looking at this completely the wrong way and theres a very simple solution using some other mongo functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `me/friends` edge to receive *all* friends (that have also authorised your app) to seed your own list. Then, you can use [Webhooks](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/v2.5) to subscribe for changes on the `User.friends` edge. When that happens, you can update your list of friends, so that your version is always up-to-date.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about web hooks. I think I'm going to take a different approach and manage friends myself so the user can select rather than just allowing all friends.